# Is there an irreducible linear representation of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ of dimension 2?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, examples-counterexamples

More explicitly, let $G$ be given by the additive group  $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

**Question**: Can there be an irreducible linear representation $\rho: G \to \operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{C}^2)$?

I am trying to construct such an example, but as time flies, I suspect that there might be none. Could you please verify my presumption and explain the reason? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Irreducible representations of abelian groups are one-dimensional.